# How to use variables from a controller in another controller in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new in AngularJS and I want to use the `username` and `password` variables that I get in this controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state, Api) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.login = function() {

        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = {}
            $state.go('tabs.extranet');
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Acceso denegado',
                template: 'Por favor, compruebe su usuario y/o contraseña'
            });
            $state.go('tabs.extranet');
        });
    };
})
```

Inside this controller

```
.controller('SaesoTabCtrl', function($scope, $sce, Saeso, Api){
    //some code....
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can add vars to `$rootScope` and access them in any controller using `$rootScope.varname`.

This is not good practice because its essentially similar to introducing global Angular variables.

A better approach, which may or may not work in your situation, is to define two controllers as follows:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">

  <!-- only MainController is accessible here -->
  <div ng-controller="InnerController">

    <!-- both MainController and InnerController are accessible here -->
    <!-- main controllers $scope variables should also be accessible in InnerController -->

  </div>

</body>
```

I would be interested if you try the latter approach to know if you got it working. This demonstrates scopical inheritance. Maybe you can make a plunker for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a *model-type* `value` or your LoginService and inject it into both controllers.  Save the data onto the service rather than the controller.

#### model

```
ngModule.value( 'session', { username:'', sessionId: '' });
```

#### session service

```
ngModule.service( 'sessionService', function(){
    var api = { username: '', sessionId: '' }
    api.doLogin = function(){}

    return api;
})
```

#### injection into controllers

```
ngModule.controller( 'LoginCtrl', function( $scope, session<Service> ){

     $scope.doLogin = function( un, pw ){
          sessionService.doLogin( un, pw )
          .then( function( rsp ){
               sessionService.username = un
               sessionService.sessionId = rsp
          })
     }
})
ngModule.controller( 'SaesoTabCtrl', function( session<Service> ){ ... })
```

***note** - I do not recommend that you store your password data in either of these solutions, this was simply to further illustrate the point.  Hopefully your login service provides a session id that expires after a certain time.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will try it

Comment: This is a possible solution and an alternative to the one i gave below

Comment: @danday74 - My problem with using the scope hierarchy (in your answer) for this type of functionality is that: It's implicitly available everywhere underneath the top-most scope, to any other scopes that inherit from it (scope inheritance, except isolate scopes); it starts treating the $scope object more like a service, blurring the SoP; it is not the recommended *angular-ish* way to handle this use case; with ng1.x & ng2 moving away from the $scope altogether, you've added an additional place where you must refactor your code if you upgrade.

Comment: jusopi, i agree with your comment and would never use the first approach i suggested but nevertheless it is A solution. The second approach is better since it at least provides an element of restricted visibility. However, in all fairness I would prefer your approach over those documented by myself :) I personally never use $scope, preferring the controller as syntax - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your data inside the [`$rootScope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope). It is accessible from anywhere in the application.