# Angular app lifetime in a browser

Tags: angularjs

I tried to google the following question, but nothing came up (which is super weird I need to).

What is an Agular app lifetime in a browser?

Or to rephrase when a user opens an Angular website, the app instances in the browser and stays live until the user leaves the website or closes the browser or?

On the separate note is it better to use a service for holding global variables (e.g. logged user name) or $rootScope?

Thanks!

Comment: Your two questions should really be broken into separate posts if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is an Agular app lifetime in a browser?

The angular app persists while that particular tab/site is open.  If you navigate away from it and then back to it, for all intents and purposes, that's a fresh instance of the application.  You could mimic a persistent session but that would entail a custom implementation on your part.

Here is a post on preserving data on a refresh of the application that you might be interested in - [AngualrJS: sustaining data on html refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617103/angualrjs-sustaining-data-on-html-refresh/12621597#12621597)

> On the separate note is it better to use a service for holding global variables (e.g. logged user name) or $rootScope?

This is well documented and you can find myriad sources both here on SO as well as the internet, but it's better to use an angular service to share data among various controllers.  It's not recommended that you pollute the $rootScope if you can avoid it.

Here is the same question asked on SO with solutions:

- [angular set a variable accessible to any scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795423/angular-set-a-variable-accessible-to-any-scope/34795878#34795878)
- [How to use variables from a controller in another controller in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795397/angular-js-use-variables-controller-in-another-controller/34795585#34795585)

Answer (score 1):

If you use angular's routing or another way to load views that doesn't reload a page, then an angular application will stay active until you leave the page (closing or refreshing).
Every time you load a page through angular its controller's data is in its initial state so any modification to a controller's data will get lost when you change page (unless you persist it somewhere, that is)

Regarding your second question, the best way should be to get a user's data after every page change (to check if the user is still logged in. Saving a user's data client side without checking if it's still valid might be a security issue). But in any case, a service is a better way to store data than using rootScope